# Points at which $f(z) = z^{2} \bar{z}$ is differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I know that $f(z)$ is diff'able at some point $z_{o}$ if the limit of the following exists:
$$ f'(z_{0})= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(z_{0}+h) - f(z_{0})}{h}.$$
In the case of $f(z) = z^{2} \bar{z}$, I have:
$$\frac{(z+h)^2(\bar{z}+\bar{h}) - z^2 \bar{z}}{h} = \frac{(2zh + h^2)\bar{z} + (z^2 + 2zh + h^2)\bar{h}}{h}. $$
Now I believe this condenses down into:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} z^2 \frac{\bar{h}}{h} .$$ 
I know this only exists at $z=0$ (as the limit at $h \to 0$ for $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$ does not exist) $-$ but what I don't understand is quite what reasoning allows the limit to be reduced to that form.

I also assume that this function would therefore be nowhere analytic?

Comment: Is $h$ complex? If so, your $f$ is not complex-differentiable.

Comment: Yes, but it is diff'able at z = 0.

Comment: If $z_0 = 0$ and $z = z_0 + h = 0 + h = h$, why do you keep carrying those $z$ and $\bar z$ after you?

Comment: because at that point I don't know $z_{0} = 0$. It represents an arbitrary point and a test of the function's differentiability in the entire complex plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Cauchy-Riemann relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations): let $z = x + \textrm i y$, so that $f(z) = \underbrace {x^3 + xy^2} _u + \textrm i \underbrace {(x^2y + y^3)} _v$.

Then,

$$\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = 3x^2 + y^2, \quad \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} = x^2 + 3y^2 \\
\frac {\partial u} {\partial y} = 2xy, \quad \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} = 2xy .$$

$f$ is differentiable precisely at those points where

$$\frac {\partial u} {\partial x} = \frac {\partial v} {\partial y} \\
\frac {\partial u} {\partial y} = - \frac {\partial v} {\partial x} ,$$

which means

$$x^2 = y^2 \\
xy = 0 .$$

The only solution is $(0,0)$, so $z_0 = 0$ is the only point where $f$ is complex-differentiable.

Comment: Thanks. I've been baldy confusing myself with the first principles idea vs the Cauchy-Riemann conditions. So, to clarify, $f(z)$ is differentiable at any points which satisfy the  Cauchy-Riemann conditions? And how do they relate to points in the complex plane at which the function is analytic?

Comment: @Garland: Remember that complex differentiability is equivalent to complex analycity; $f$ is complex-differentiable (read: complex-analytic) only at those points where the Cauchy-Riemann relations hold.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\frac{(2zh + h^2)\bar{z} + (z^2 + 2zh + h^2)\bar{h}}{h}=
2z\bar{z}+h\bar{z}+z^2\frac{\bar{h}}{h}+2z+h\bar{h}
$$
and all summands have limit for $h\to0$ except, perhaps $z^2\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$.

If $z=0$, this has limit $0$, so the function is differentiable at $0$. If $z\ne0$, the limit exists if and only if
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\bar{h}}{h}
$$
exists, which it doesn't. Just approach $0$ along the real axis, which has limit $1$ and along the imaginary axis, which has limit $-1$.